# How to add clickable menu drawer?

Tags: android, menu, drawer

I have this code in order to create a menu drawer, but I don't know how to switch the layouts on a button click in the menu. Can someone please help me?

My other Xml files are xml1 and xml2.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener, View.OnClickListener {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.Toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.closed);
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        NavigationView nv = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav1);
        nv.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case (R.id.nav_sages):
                        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity( in );
                    case (R.id.nav_Satz):
                        Intent int1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(int1);
                    case (R.id.nav_auserdem):
                        Intent in2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(in2);
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

hey you are doing it wrong here,

```
Intent in = new Intent("here you need to mention your current 
activity,getApplicationContext() works here no problem","and here you need to 
mention 2nd activity, i.e., the activity which you want to navigate");
            startActivity(in);
```

for example: Consider two activity MainActivity & Main2Activity;
so now if you are in MainActivity and want to navigate to Main2Activity : the code will be as follows

```
Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(in);
```

or you can do like this also:

```
Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(in);
```

hope it'll help

Comment: But to I need to create a new activity or can I just create a new Layout xml?

Comment: you need to create new activity @Jessef